# Customized Drupal with pre-installed modules

Tags: drupal, build, installation

I heard in Joomla world they sometimes create so called builds - Joomla installs targeted for specific kind of site. Is there something similar for Drupal?

Someone may have likely created e.g. Company site with the same set of pages time and again, and it's possible that such builds are offered somewhere. I don't know how personal or commercial these builds can be, but I am sure some people can use them to speed up their development.

What are your ideas, have there been such sites or attempts, is this a right approach?

Answer (score 2):

They're called [Install Profiles](http://drupal.org/node/67921).  There's a [bunch of contributed profiles](http://drupal.org/project/installation+profiles) on the Drupal site.

Comment: I can see that profiles from the link above don't actually contain modules themselves. Should I still download the modules manually in addition to downloading the profile?

Answer (score 0):

> I can see that profiles from the link above don't actually contain modules themselves. Should I still download the modules manually in addition to downloading the profile?

Profiles can have a **`modules`** subdirectory for modules included with the installation profile.

AFAIK you need to download the modules manually if this directory is not populated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good ones I didn't see listed on the Drupal profiles page.

They are [iSite Essentials CMS](http://www.leveltendesign.com/l10apps/cms) and [Acquia Drupal](http://acquia.com/).